# How to edit multiple records in certain column mysql database using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update

I have multiple records of the structure in the 'column1' column that I want to update the type in the same column.

These fields contain information about the language, categories level and name, in only one FIELD.

Information is separated by symbols as follows:

1. " : " (two points) separating language by root( language% : Top/% )
2. " / " ( Slash ) separating root ( Top / level_1) by category, and category (level_1 / level_2 ) by different level category.
3. So the FIELD will have the following form "language:Top/level/level"

Information stored on FIELDS comes from two different sources one is internal and the other FIELDS without root( Top/ ) come from an external source and must be updated by SQL

Real example field:

**before**

&lt;b&gt;Englisch&lt;/b&gt;:level/Test/later

**after**

&lt;b&gt;Englisch&lt;/b&gt;:Top/level/Test/later

Real example table:

```
**before**                                           **after**
language0:Top/level_0/name_category                  language0:Top/level_1/name_category
language1:name_test2/name_category                   language1:name_test2/name_category
language2:level_1/name_category                      language2:Top/level_1/level_2/name_category
language3:level_1/level_2/name_category              language3:Top/level_1/level_2/name_category
language4:level_1/level_2/level_3/name_category      language4:Top/level_1/level_2/level_3/name_category
```

first line have already changed so we need to SELECT only those record that start with "language%:level_1/%"

**table_example1**

```
id    **column1**                       

1    language0:Top/level_1/level_2/level_3/level_4
2    language1:name_test2/etc/
3    language2:level_1/level_2/level_3/level_4
4    language3:level_1/level_2/level_3
5    language3:level_1/level_2
6    language%:level_1/
```

Note:

- Only these fields must be updated in the example: line id 3,4,5,6 and only column1 in the table
- The results must be like line id 1 column1: `language0:Top/name_test/etc/etc/`.
- The field `language1:name_test2/etc/` in line id 2 column1 will be ignored is diferent format and stored diferent information.
- Basis for not changing line 2 is different link value: name_test2(name_test) LIKE 'name_test/%' only
- this # symbol not exist in the field is only to delineate you can see before column, after column
- The FIELD should be updated only if after the following two points ( : )there is exactly the expression followed by the slash (level_1/)

Other records that start otherwise must not be modified.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the basis for not changing line 2?  Is it that there is no hash `#` symbol after the colon `:`?  So, is the requirement to change `:#` into `:Top/`?  If so, then the tabular 'From' column needs to be revised, though I took what you had written out verbatim to make that mapping table.

Comment: Rephrase the note. Line 6 does not include even language. Please clarify your criteria. If you had completed your question before `table_example1`, then it was clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table_example1` SET `column1` = REPLACE(column1,':name_test/',':Top/name_test/');
```

CREATE THE BACKUP BEFORE USING THIS QUERY.

Comment: Nice you save my life, Best regards for moment i have only 10 point required 15 for voting, later im vote your answer, Sincerly have nice day